# UIBarButtonItem Appearance not working with resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, scaling, appearance

PROBLEM:  Scaling of UIBarButtonItem background image is not being obeyed as per [resizableImageWithCapInsets](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) when set using the [Appearance Proxy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

I have set up a project with a few test assets for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have a background image, and two icon images for my UIBarButtonItem's.  They are:

Background (50x34):

[image: Background Image]

Icons (30x30):

[image: Circle Icon]
[image: Square Icon]

These icons are the @2x versions (hence they are double the sizes listed above), but rest assured I have the standard assets in the project, too (at half the size)

Creative, I know!  But here's the issue--I would like some extra padding on my button background image so that the icons scale only the green section of the background image.  Here's the code I have in my AppDelegate:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"testbutton2"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 20, 16, 20)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works all well and good for the first instance of a UIBarButtonItem.  However for every succeeding instance, the resizable part of the image is completely ignored.  Check it out:

[image: Erroneous background images]

So as you see, on screen one, everything goes as planned.  However, every succeeding use of the UIBarButtonItem is NOT scaled correctly.

Now, I did manage to fix this issue.  I had to set the appearance on every instance of a UIBarButtonItem.  I did this by having a common UIViewController superclass that all view controllers inherited from.  In it, I had the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"testbutton2"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 20, 16, 20)];

    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:bgImage
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:bgImage
                                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Which yields the following results:

[image: Correct Button Backgrounds]

So I guess I figured out a solution for the issue, but I remain a bit perplexed as to why my original implementation didn't work.  It seems to me that the appearance proxy is intended to be used such that you don't have to change the appearance of each individual instance of an object--exactly what I had to end up doing.  Can anybody explain to me what's happening here?  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?